Boot signed vanilla kernel : error: bad shim signature
Using Knoppix 9.1 I installed grub.
This grub (2.06( is working OK under secured boot.
Then I signed a vanilla kernel (4.9.20). When I tried to boot this signed kernel using the signed grub I got:
error: bad shim signature
The output of : sbverify --list shimx64.efi.signed is:
signature 1

image signature issuers:

- /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Corporation UEFI CA 2011

image signature certificates:

- subject: /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Windows UEFI Driver Publisher

   issuer:  /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Corporation UEFI CA 2011

- subject: /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Corporation UEFI CA 2011

   issuer:  /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Corporation Third Party Marketplace Root

The output of : sbverify --list bzImage.signed
signature 1

image signature issuers:

- /C=CA/ST=Quebec/L=Montreal/O=cyphermox/CN=Secure Boot Signing/emailAddress=example@example.com

image signature certificates:

- subject: /C=CA/ST=Quebec/L=Montreal/O=cyphermox/CN=Secure Boot Signing/emailAddress=example@example.com

   issuer:  /C=CA/ST=Quebec/L=Montreal/O=cyphermox/CN=Secure Boot Signing/emailAddress=example@example.com

After signing the kernel I ran:
mokutil --import MOK.der + reboot
After reboot, I got the shim blue screens in order to enroll the new key.
Is it possible to see more debug info ?
How can I make sure the mokutil procedure ended OK ?
Thank you,
Zvika

I made the following modifications and now it works:

Modified mokconfig.cnf
#HOME = . #RANDFILE = $ENV::HOME/.rnd
[ req ] distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name x509_extensions = v3 string_mask = utf8only prompt = no
[ req_distinguished_name ] countryName = IL stateOrProvinceName = IL localityName = Ashdod 0.organizationName = Elta Systems commonName = Secure Boot Signing Key emailAddress = veredz@elta.co.il
[ v3 ] subjectKeyIdentifier = hash authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always,issuer basicConstraints = critical,CA:FALSE extendedKeyUsage = codeSigning, **1.3.6.1.4.1.2312.16.1.3** nsComment = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"


After running mokutil --import MOK.der + reboot, I removed Knoppix 9.1 DOK from the PC. And then enrolled the key using shim blue windows.


I can't tell which of the steps made the change.
